How to calculate ratios of times taken for a planet to trace areas in an elliptical orbit
Assuming that the eccentricity of a planet's elliptic orbit is small ($0<e \ll 1$), show that the ratio of the times taken by the planet to travel over the two parts of its orbit separated by the minor axis is approximately $1 + \frac{4e}{\pi}$.
In all honesty, I am clueless on how to approach this. However, here is the feeble attempt I have made thus far:
I have that the quantity $h=r^2 \dot{\theta}$ is a constant in plane polar co-ordinates, and that $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} r^2 \dot{\theta} dt = \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}r^2 d\theta$ gives the area swept by the planet in the time from $t_1$ to $t_2$. Thus, without loss of generality if I assume that the planet starts at $t=0$ on the minor axis, and call $t_1$ the time it takes to sweep around the perihelion side of the orbit to the other side of the minor axis, and then call $t_2$ the time at which the planet returns to the position $t=0$. Also, worth noting that in this co-ordinate system that the origin is fixed at the centre of mass of the system (approximately the position of the star. For all intents and purposes, the star's position is at $\mathbf{0}$).
With this, I have that the area of the perihelion side of the orbit is given by $\int_{0}^{t_1}r^2 \dot{\theta}dt=ht_1$, where $h=r^2\dot{\theta}$. Also, the area of the aphelion side of the orbit is given by $\int_{t_1}^{t_2}r^2\dot{\theta}dt=h(t_2-t_1)$. Also, the ratio of times taken to sweep out these parts of the orbit is simply $\frac{t_2-t_1}{t_1}=\frac{t_2}{t_1}-1$.
These areas clearly sum to the area of the ellipse, so $ht_2=\pi ab$, where $a,b$ are the semi-major and semi-minor axes respectively. Also, since from $t=0$ to $t=t_1$, the planet sweeps half of its orbit, we have $ht_1=\frac{1}{2}\pi ab$. This seems to lead to the ratio of times being equal to $1$ which obviously is false. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I think you are misunderstanding what a minor axis is. It passes through the centre of the ellipse, which obviously cuts the ellipse into two equal halves. On the other hand, the star (at the origin) is at one of the foci of the ellipse (the centre is the midpoint of the two foci).

Perhaps you mean the latus rectum of the ellipse (which does pass through a focus) instead of minor axis?

I understand this, although trawling through my work again I have noticed that I did make this mistake by treating it as if the origin was at the centre. I am working on fixing this and hopefully I can reach the correct answer


Let the sun be at focus point A. Notice that you are comparing times that planet (its radius-vector $\vec{AP}$) needs to "sweep" two different areas. While travelling along the "right" half of the ellipse, vector $\vec{AP}$ is blue. While travelling along the left half of the ellipse, $\vec{AP}$ is green. So you have the area of the ellipse divided into two parts: one swept by blue vector ($A_1$) and one swept by green vector ($A_2$). Contour of area $A_1$ consists of elliptical arc FHE and straight lines EA and AF. Contour of area $A_2$ consists of elliptical arc EVF and straight lines FA and AE.
According to Kepler laws, a line segment joining a planet and the Sun sweeps out equal areas during equal intervals of time. So the ratio of times needed to sweep the "blue" and "green" part of the ellipse is equal to the ratio of areas $A_1$ and $A_2$:
$$\frac{t_1}{t_2}=\frac{A_1}{A_2}$$
If you denote the longer semi-axis of the ellipse with $DV=a$, shorter one with $DE=b$, eccentricity with $e$, then $DA=f=ae$.
The following should be obvious:
$$A_1=\frac12A_{ellipse} + A_{\triangle AEF}$$
$$A_2=\frac12A_{ellipse} - A_{\triangle AEF}$$
$$A_{ellipse}=ab\pi$$
$$A_{\triangle AEF}=\frac12 FE \cdot DA=\frac 12 2bf=abe$$
$$\frac{t_1}{t_2}=\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{\frac12 ab\pi+abe}{\frac12 ab\pi-abe}=\frac{\frac12\pi+e}{\frac12\pi-e}=\frac{\pi + 2e}{\pi - 2e}=1+\frac{4e}{\pi - 2e}$$
For very small values of $e \ll 1$, the denominator of the fraction is approximately equal to $\pi$ and therefore:
$$\frac{t_1}{t_2}\approx 1+\frac{4e}\pi$$
Exactly what you are expecting.
